Text inside of circles and also inside of their intersection with html/css?
I'm trying to find a solid way to represent this:

I have the code below so far, but as expected, text 2 will easily overflow the shape as it's placed with position: absolute. Can anyone help me think a better approach? I'd be inifinitely grateful.


html{
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#circles-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
}

.circle > div{
  width: 50%;
}

#circle-1 > div{
  margin-right: 50%;
}

#circle-3 > div{
  margin-left: 50%;
}

#circle-1{
  background-color: #3a7487;
  transform: translateX(25%)
}

#circle-3{
  background-color: #9d4767;
  transform: translateX(-25%);
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}

#intersection{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
<main>
      <div id="circles-container">
      <div class="circle" id="circle-1"> <div>Text 1</div> </div>
      <div class="circle" id="intersection"> <div>Text 2</div> </div>
      <div class="circle" id="circle-3"> <div>Text 3</div> </div>
      </div>
     </main>




You can use word-wrap property and set it to break-word, it

allows long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line. link



html{
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#circles-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
}

.circle > div{
  width: 50%;
}

#circle-1 > div{
  margin-right: 50%;
}

#circle-3 > div{
  margin-left: 50%;
}

#circle-1{
  background-color: #3a7487;
  transform: translateX(25%)
}

#circle-3{
  background-color: #9d4767;
  transform: translateX(-25%);
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}

#intersection{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-wrap: wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 20px;


}
<main>
      <div id="circles-container">
      <div class="circle" id="circle-1"> <div>Text 1</div> </div>
      <div class="circle" id="intersection"> <div> VeryVeryLongTOOLongText 2</div> </div>
      <div class="circle" id="circle-3"> <div>Text 3</div> </div>
      </div>
     </main>



Note:
Text overflowing has nothing to do with position: absolute;

Thank you! I still feel like it's dangerous to have text inside of an "invisible div" because if the text is too long it will come out of the intersection, but will use fixed sizes and also your approach to make it look as good as possible.

@Nellie do you want the intersection expand dynamically to adjust the text if text gets too long ? It means at certain point, those two circles also should get big, otherwise when text is too long, interaction extends becoming an overlapping circle.

Yep, I would expect them to expand dynamically!
